# Writing Strings to File

Tags: c, file

So what I'm trying to do is write these to file in sequence. I thought of using a 'for' loop, but I'm not sure how to go about that, because the code wouldn't work properly if I used stri with i as a variable. I'm basically just looking for suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
int main(void)              //Main calls the functions.  

FILE *fp_out; 

char str1[] = "That means today is Monday! \n";
char str2[] = "That means today is Tuesday! \n";
char str3[] = "That means today is Wednesday! \n";
char str4[] = "That means today is Thursday! \n";
char str5[] = "That means today is Friday! \n";

fp_out = fopen("strings.txt", "w");

//int i;
//for (i=1; i>5; i++)
//{
//fputs(str[i]
```

The last lines are commented out, but they were the start of the for loop I attempted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've used different variable names for each string, you can't do this in a loop directly (without making an array of those pointers).  It may be simpler to just put your strings in an array to begin with:

```
const char * str[5] = {
    "That means today is Monday! \n",
    "That means today is Tuesday! \n",
    "That means today is Wednesday! \n",
    "That means today is Thursday! \n",
    "That means today is Friday! \n"
};
```

Then you can loop through as normal:

```
for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) fputs( str[i], fp_out );
```

This is subtly different from your original approach.  Because yours were declared as `char` arrays, you are actually allowed to modify them, whereas the string literals I've used here are constant (even if you omit the `const` keyword).  But I think you didn't want to be modifying them during execution anyway.

Comment: +1 because I had no idea you could declare 2d strings like that

Comment: This is exactly what I was intending to do, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop if you store all your strings in a single array:

```
char *strings[] = {str1, str2, str3, str4, str5};
```

You can now iterate through the array using an index and write each string individually:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    fputs(strings[i], fp_out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *strs[] = {
      "That means today is Monday! \n",
      "That means today is Tuesday! \n",
      "That means today is Wednesday! \n",
      "That means today is Thursday! \n",
      "That means today is Friday! \n",
      0
    };
    FILE *fp_out = fopen("strings.txt", "w");
    for (char **p = strs; *p; p++) {
        fprintf(fp_out, "%s", *p);
    }
    fclose(fp_out);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the array as others have indicated is probably the approach you are looking for. But, you could also use `<stdarg.h>`, and a function that takes a variable number of arguments:

```
void print_strings (FILE *fp_out, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fp_out);
    for (const char *p; (p = va_arg(ap, const char *)); /*empty*/) {
        fputs(p, fp_out);
    }
    va_end(ap);
}

/* ... */
print_strings(fp_out, str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, (const char *)0);
```

The cast on the sentinel value is necessary to prevent an `int` argument to be put into the function, since the function expects only `const char *` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer by @paddy:

```
const char * str[5] = {
    "That means today is Monday! \n",
    "That means today is Tuesday! \n",
    "That means today is Wednesday! \n",
    "That means today is Thursday! \n",
    "That means today is Friday! \n"
};
```

What happens if you add Saturday and Sunday?  You need to change the `5` to a `7`.  The good news: if you forget to make the change, the C compiler will notice that the number of strings is different from the declared size of the array, and you will get an error.

But hmm.  Then why do we have to specify the length of the array?  Can't the C compiler just figure out how long it should be for us?

In fact, yes.  All we have to do is leave out the number, and the C compiler will count the number of things in the array and make the array exactly that size.

But then, when we go to print the strings, how do we know how many there are?  There are two common ways to solve this problem.

One is to put a special marker at the end of the array, usually called a "sentinel" value.  A good choice here would be `NULL`.

So let's make those changes to the example: have the compiler count for us, and add a sentinel at the end:

Here is the answer by @paddy:

```
char const *str[] = {
    "That means today is Monday! \n",
    "That means today is Tuesday! \n",
    "That means today is Wednesday! \n",
    "That means today is Thursday! \n",
    "That means today is Friday! \n",
    NULL
};
```

Now we can rewrite the loop to check for the sentinel value:

```
for (i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    fputs(str[i], fp_out);
```

This loops and prints until the value of `str[i]` becomes false.  A `NULL` pointer will evaluate false, stopping the loop.

The other way to know how many things are in the list is a little bit more tricky.  We can use the `sizeof()` feature to find out the size of the array, but this size is given in terms of `sizeof(char)` (on most platforms, this means bytes).  But we can divide the total size by the size of one element.  This would work:

```
static int const str_count = sizeof(str) / sizeof(char const *);
```

But what happens if you change the type of `str`?  Then you need to remember to change it in the `sizeof(char const *)`.  Better, you can use `str` itself to figure out the size of an element.  Like so:

```
static int const str_count = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]);
```

We can even pack this up into a macro:

```
#define ARRAY_LEN(a)  (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))

static int const str_count = ARRAY_LEN(str);
```

Here's the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < str_count; ++i)
    fputs(str[i], fp_out);
```

or, with the macro:

```
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN(str); ++i)
    fputs(str[i], fp_out);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `for` loop if, instead of creating five separate arrays, you created an `array of arrays`:

```
char* strings[5];
strings[0] = "That means today is Monday! \n";
strings[1] = "That means today is Tuesday! \n";
...
```

Then your for loop needs to print `strings[i]`, with `i` ranging from 0 to 4.

Comment: This answer does not write the output as requested.